# Is it necessary to override hashcode method in non hashed datastructure

Tags: java, hashmap, equals, hashcode

What I understand from hashcode method for objects in Java: it is required to calculate the hashcode of objects which in turn is used to calculate the index / bucket location of the object in a hashed datastructure like hashMap.

So will it be correct to say that for a class that is not to be used along with a hashed datastructure doesnt need to have hashCode() method implemented in it? in other words is overriding the equals() method  enough for non hashed datastructures?

Also please correct  me if my assumption is wrong .

Comment: if you want correct code, it is required. It's nice to say it'll never be used in such ways, but it's practically impossible in actual code to make such guarantees

Comment: It's easy to say that you don't use a hashed datastructure. But first you put some known objects into a `List` and use `contains()` to check whether a specific item is in that list and everything works. Two weeks later you decide that it is better to use a `Set` to hold the known items and - boom - the code no longer works because you didn't override `hashCode()`

Comment: The `hashCode()` contract requires that equal objects have equal hash codes. Even if you don't think you'll use it, it's not a good idea to break contracts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In theory, you are correct: if you **know** that your object will never be used in any way that requires the hash code, then not implementing `hashCode` will not cause anything bad to happen.

In practice there are reasons not to rely on this fact:

1. code changes and an objects that were initially planned to only ever exist in non-hashed structures get put into sets or used as the key to maps, because requirements change. If you don't implement `hashCode` then, things can go bad.
2. if you implement `equals` and you don't implement `hashCode` then you are almost certainly breaking the contract of `hashCode` that requires it to be consistent to `equals`. If *your* code breaks a contract that other code depends on, then that other code can silently fail in unexpected/weird ways.
3. in order to avoid mistakes it's usually best to let your IDE generate `equals` anyway and if you do that generating the appropriate `hashCode` at the same time is no extra effort.

Note that all of this assumes you even want to implement `equals`: If you don't care about equality of an object entirely (which is actually very common, not every type needs a specific equality definition), then you can just leave `equals` **and** `hashCode` out of your code and it's all conforming ('though your type might not match the "intuitive" equality definition of your type then).

Comment: *breaking the contract of `equals`*... Technically it's the contract of `hashCode`.

Comment: @shmosel: you are correct, I've fixed that statement.